# Getting colour palette from a photoshop file

Tags: photoshop, palette

I have a photoshop file with several layers (all shapes, no bitmaps). Is there any automatic way I could extract the colours from all these shapes into a palette? Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that from the commandline with ImageMagick if you want to. It is installed on most Linux distros and available for Mac OSX and Windows.

So, if I start with this Photoshop file:

[image]

and do this:

```
convert image.psd -flatten -unique-colors palette.png
```

I get this (I have enlarged it 5000% so you can see it):

[image]

Or, if you want it as text:

```
convert image.psd -flatten -unique-colors txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 5,1,255,srgb
0,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
1,0: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  red
2,0: (0,255,0)  #00FF00  lime
3,0: (0,0,255)  #0000FF  blue
4,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your source image, I can't say for sure, but as far as I know, the only real palette exists with bitmap images of indexed color.

So you'd change your color mode to "indexed", giving you a 256 color palette ready for export. 
Depending on your use case that may already be enough – you can also try to export a file with as few colors as possible (saving a GIF), giving you the opportunity to filter down on the most used colors in your image.